# android : setting font style for different dimension

Tags: android, fonts, dimensions

I want to give a lato thin style for devices width more than 620dp. Can this be set using dimens file. I am using dimens to set the text size for various size devices but how the text font can be set based on the dimensions

Comment: The idea of font style should be independent of font size. Changing font is not a good idea IMO

Answer (score 0):

You could use a string resources file for that (`strings-font.xml` or something like that) and create a new configuration for width larger than 620dp.

Inside these files, you could set the font name you want to use for each configuration.

Hope it helps!